# Starting new activity onClick

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an android application for my web service.

I've added a register TextView to the main activity and added this code for the onClickListener:

```
mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
     startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
  }
});
```

When the register TextView is clicked, this error is returned in logcat:

```
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{us.picbox/us.picbox.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at us.picbox.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:85)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
01-01 01:36:29.443: E/AndroidRuntime(21558):    ... 11 more
```

Could anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at us.picbox.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:85)`The problem start on line 85 in RegisterActivity. Post RegisterActivity's `onCreate()` method and indicate which line is 85.

Comment: Are you declared RegisterActivity in manifest?

Comment: Declare a activity in manifest.. !!

Comment: I see where the issue is, this is line 85:    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
      attemptLogin();
     }
    });

But that is non-existant on the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see where the issue is, this is line 85:
>
> ```
> findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>     @Override 
>     public void onClick(View view) { 
>         attemptLogin(); 
>     } 
> });
> ```
>
> But that is non-existant on the layout.

`findViewById()` cannot locate a View that is not currently displayed. You *must* have a View with `android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"` in the view hierarchy otherwise `findViewById()` will return `null` and cause this NullPointerException.